# Banana sprite js bespoke forward and backward animations with json data

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I need to create some custom scroll animations - and wanted to start exploring animating a simple block.

[image]

Using json - I want to provide the skeleton for the block (classname, height, width, background), then the actions per start/end frames which relates to the scroll value.

how do I modify the code -- to handle the forward/backward animations for the block using the data json

So in this example.

-- when the scroll is at 0 -- or start of application - create the block.
[image]

-- if the scroll is between a range 100-400 - the scroll is instructed to move right.
[image]

-- if the scroll hits over 400 - destroy the block.

so the animation is to take hold in a forward direction, but I want to reverse the animations in the opposite direction - so the timeline can be moved forward, backward - dependent on the speed of the scroll - so a slowmo or speedup affect can take hold

This is the first step - for adding more complicated animations, longer intricate ones, with multiple objects.

I have tried to capture the translate details so the untouched x or y translation in place doesn't get overridden - but I think there is a bug....

please review 
[Get translate3d values of a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982053/get-translate3d-values-of-a-div)

//jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/g10qe5m6/6/

```
var data = [{
  "structure": {
    "name": "square",
    "height": 30,
    "width": 30,
    "x": 10,
    "y": 10,
    "background": 'url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/74/f3/5d/74f35d5885e8eb858e6af6b5a7844379.jpg")'
  },
  "frames": [{
    "create": [{
      "s": 0
    }, {
      "e": 0
    }]
  }, {
    "moveRight": [{
      "s": 1
    }, {
      "e": 400
    }]
  }, {
    "destroy": [{
      "s": 400
    }, {
      "e": 400
    }]
  }]
}]

//console.log(data)

function getCurrentValues(el) {
  var results = $(el).css('transform').match(/matrix(?:(3d)\(\d+(?:, \d+)*(?:, (\d+))(?:, (\d+))(?:, (\d+)), \d+\)|\(\d+(?:, \d+)*(?:, (\d+))(?:, (\d+))\))/)

if(!results) return [0, 0, 0];
if(results[1] == '3d') return results.slice(2,5);

results.push(0);
return results.slice(5, 8);
};


var animations = {
  createObj: function(obj) {
    //create object
    var block = $('<div></div>');
    $(block).addClass(obj.name);
    $(block).addClass("animatedblock");
    $(block).css("height", obj.height);
    $(block).css("width", obj.width);
    $(block).css("transform", 'translate(' + obj.x + 'px, ' + obj.y + 'px)');
    $(block).css("background", obj.background);
  $(block).css("background-size", "cover");

    $('.container').append($(block));
  },
  deleteObj: function(el) {
    //destroy object
    el.remove()
  },
  moveRight: function(el, pixels) {
    //el.css('')
    //move right

  console.log("x", getCurrentValues(el)[0])
   console.log("y", getCurrentValues(el)[1])

  el.css('transform', 'translate(' + pixels + 'px, ' + getCurrentValues(el)[1] + 'px');

    //el.css('transform', 'translate(' + pixels + 'px, ' + getCurrentValues(el).y + 'px');
  },
  moveLeft: function(el, pixels) {
    //move left     
    //el.css('transform', 'translate(' + -pixels + 'px, ' + getCurrentValues(el).y + 'px');


  console.log("x", getCurrentValues(el)[0])
   console.log("y", getCurrentValues(el)[1])


  el.css('transform', 'translate(' + -pixels + 'px, ' + getCurrentValues(el)[1] + 'px');

  },
  moveDown: function(el, pixels) {
    //move down     
    //el.css('transform', 'translate(' + getValues(el).x + 'px, ' + pixels + 'px)');


  el.css('transform', 'translate(' + getCurrentValues(el)[0] + 'px, ' + pixels + 'px');


  },
  moveUp: function(el, pixels) {
    //move up       
    // el.css('transform', 'translate(' + getValues(el).x + 'px, ' + -pixels + 'px)');

        el.css('transform', 'translate(' + getCurrentValues(el)[0] + 'px, ' + -pixels + 'px');

  }
}



//app.deleteObj($('.square'));

//data.skeleton

/*
    var instructor = {
      action: function(data, position) {

        console.log("position", position)

        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
          //alert(item.PageName);
          console.log("item", item.frames)
        });
      }
    }
*/


var frames = data[0].frames;

var instructor = {
  action: function(scroll, direction) {

    var sequence = [{
      "create": 0,
      "moveRight": 100,
      "moveDown": 200,
      "destroy": 400
    }]

    //if down - forward animation

    //if up - reverse animation

    ///use the data to detect what the block can do at what start and end frame
    if (scroll == 0) {
      //create block
      //animations.createObj(data[0].structure);
    }

    if (scroll > 100 && scroll < 400) {
      //move right
      animations.moveRight($('.square'), scroll);
    }


    if (scroll > 400 && scroll < 800) {
      //move right
      animations.moveDown($('.square'), scroll);
    }

    if (scroll > 800) {
      //animations.deleteObj($('.square'));
    }


    //move left
    //animations.moveLeft($('.square'), scroll);

  }
}



animations.createObj(data[0].structure);

var position = $(window).scrollTop();

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  console.log("scroll", scroll);

  if (scroll > position) {
    console.log('scrollDown');
    instructor.action(scroll, "down");
  } else {
    console.log('scrollUp');
    instructor.action(scroll, "up");
  }
  position = scroll;

});
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how do I modify the code -- to handle the forward/backward animations for the block using the data json

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g10qe5m6/2/  - I've tried to enhance this so it will moveLeft, then moveDown -- but I need to capture the current translate values

Comment: this is a good demo - how is it working -- you included the x, y end positions throughout the animation frames? What does the subscribe do? How will this work with multiple objects -- if you want to create or destroy them as part of the animation sequence

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2tzefkuw/ -- doesn't seem to be working with multiple blocks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though the question is too broad to address in a single answer, I would try to give you
an idea. Break your code to small modules to handle scroll event and animation actions.
The subscribe method is used to bind event listeners in Observable pattern. The rest of
the code is self explanatory. Comment below if you have any queries.

```js
let data = [{
    "structure": {
      "name": "square",
      "height": 30,
      "width": 30,
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0,
      "background": 'url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/74/f3/5d/74f35d5885e8eb858e6af6b5a7844379.jpg")'
    },
    "frames": [{
      "animation": "move",
      "start": 0,
      "stop": 300,
      "startPositionX": 0,
      "startPositionY": 0,
      "endPositionX": 90,
      "endPositionY": 0,
    }, {
      "animation": "move",
      "start": 301,
      "stop": 600,
      "startPositionX": 90,
      "startPositionY": 0,
      "endPositionX": 90,
      "endPositionY": 80,
    }, {
      "animation": "move",
      "start": 601,
      "stop": 900,
      "startPositionX": 90,
      "startPositionY": 80,
      "endPositionX": 0,
      "endPositionY": 0,
    }, {
      "animation": "show",
      "start": 601,
      "stop": 9999,
      "positionX": 0,
      "positionY": 0,
    }],
  },
  {
    "structure": {
      "name": "pear",
      "height": 30,
      "width": 30,
      "x": 90,
      "y": 80,
      "background": 'url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/74/f3/5d/74f35d5885e8eb858e6af6b5a7844379.jpg")'
    },
    "frames": [{
      "animation": "move",
      "start": 0,
      "stop": 300,
      "startPositionX": 90,
      "startPositionY": 80,
      "endPositionX": 0,
      "endPositionY": 80,
    }, {
      "animation": "move",
      "start": 301,
      "stop": 600,
      "startPositionX": 0,
      "startPositionY": 80,
      "endPositionX": 0,
      "endPositionY": 0,
    }, {
      "animation": "move",
      "start": 601,
      "stop": 900,
      "startPositionX": 0,
      "startPositionY": 0,
      "endPositionX": 90,
      "endPositionY": 80,
    }, {
      "animation": "show",
      "start": 601,
      "stop": 9999,
      "positionX": 90,
      "positionY": 80,
    }],
  }
]

let animations = {
  setup: function($container) {
    this.$container = $container;
    this.viewportWidth = $container.width();
    this.viewportHeight = $container.height();
  },
  createBlock: function(blockSpec) {
    let $block = $('<div>');
    $block.addClass(blockSpec.name);
    $block.addClass("animatedblock");
    $block.css("height", blockSpec.height);
    $block.css("width", blockSpec.width);
    $block.css("background", blockSpec.background);
    $block.css("background-size", "cover");
    this.$container.append($block);
    this.setPosition($block, blockSpec.x, blockSpec.y)
    return $block;
  },
  setPosition($block, x, y) {
    $block.css({
      left: x / 100 * this.viewportWidth,
      top: y / 100 * this.viewportHeight,
    });
  },
  moveBlock($block, frame, scrollProgress) {
    let blockPositionX = frame.startPositionX + scrollProgress * (frame.endPositionX - frame.startPositionX);
    let blockPositionY = frame.startPositionY + scrollProgress * (frame.endPositionY - frame.startPositionY);
    this.setPosition($block, blockPositionX, blockPositionY);
  },
  showBlock: function($block, frame) {
    $block.show()
    this.setPosition($block, frame.positionX, frame.positionY);
  },
  hideBlock: function($block) {
    $block.hide()
  },
}

class ScrollObserver {
  constructor() {
    let $window = $(window);
    this.STOP_DISPATCH = 'STOP_DISPATCH';
    this.subscribers = [];
    $window.scroll(event => this.dispatch($window.scrollTop()));
  }
  subscribe(subscriberFn) {
    this.subscribers.push(subscriberFn);
  }
  dispatch(scrollPosition) {
    for (let subscriberFn of this.subscribers) {
      if (subscriberFn(scrollPosition) == this.STOP_DISPATCH) break;
    }
  }
}

jQuery(function($) {
  animations.setup($('.container'));
  $(window).resize(event => animations.setup($('.container')));
  for (let obj of data) {
    let scrollObserver = new ScrollObserver();
    let blockSpec = obj.structure;
    let $block = animations.createBlock(blockSpec);
    for (let frame of obj.frames) {
      scrollObserver.subscribe(scrollPosition => {
        if (scrollPosition >= frame.start && scrollPosition <= frame.stop) {
          let scrollProgress = (scrollPosition - frame.start) / (frame.stop - frame.start);
          switch (frame.animation) {
            case 'move':
              animations.moveBlock($block, frame, scrollProgress);
              break;
            case 'show':
              animations.showBlock($block, frame);
          }
          return scrollObserver.STOP_DISPATCH;
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1500px;
}

.container {
  background: grey;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.animatedblock {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: what if you need to scale the animation panel to make it responsive? Why wasn't it working for multiple units earlier on? https://jsfiddle.net/d4053upt/1/

Comment: It was not working for `scrollObserver`, if you need to make it responsive, your json needs to set positions in a fixed maze (say 100x100), then you scale it according to window size.

Comment: Could you implement that change - as its part of the bounty

Comment: could you implement the resizing capabilities as part of the bounty satisfaction

Comment: I've tried to invoke the hide feature -- but it seems to malfunction the animations --- ideally want to be able to fade in the blocks --- then after animations fade out --- and reverse if the direction changes.

Comment: I've started to add fadeins and outs -- but I don't this is clean or stable. this may work but needs stabilization -- this offers a scrollable navigation control-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56916705/gradual-fadein-fadeout-based-on-the-scroll @Munim Munna